# Shopify dynamic page content

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have a Shopify theme which I would like to add a Custom Post Type like Wordpress has.

I created a new page template called page.project and created some snippets that can be added to one of my project pages. I found this worked well until I added a second project and the data on each page.project was cloned through each.

Is there a way I can add a page.project to Shopify that can be re-used with different data snippets on each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a custom post type like WordPress in Shopify.

But you can have multiply blogs which in a sense are custom post types.

But the only ( easy way ) to have dynamic sections is to have Metafields for the page or use an application like Shogun https://apps.shopify.com/shogun to populate the data.